# Firebase emulator wont run

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-tools

I'm using the Firebase emulator in order to test my Cloud Function. The code I'm trying to execute is:

```
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";

const fetch = require('node-fetch');

export const newZipCode = functions.database.ref('/zipCodes/{zipCode}').onCreate(async (snapshot, context) => {
    const api = await fetch(`https://api.papapi.se/lite/?query=${context.params.zipCode}&format=json&apikey=xxx`);
    const json = await api.json();

    console.log(context.params.zipCode);

    if (api.ok) {
        snapshot.ref.update({
            latitude: json.results[0].latitude,
            longitude: json.results[0].longitude
        });
    } else {
        console.log(${api.status}));
    }
});
```

However, when I try to run the Firestore- and Functions emulators, I receive this error message:

> "Missing expected firebase config value databaseURL, config is actually{"storageBucket":"xxxx-yyyy.appspot.com","projectId":"xxxx-yyyy"}"

Shouldn't Cloud Functions and Firestore emulators be able to communicate right of the box? If not, what needs to be done in order to get the emulators running? FYI, I'm running Node.js 14 and Firebase version 9.6.1.

Comment: How do you start the emulator?

Comment: @fjc "firebase emulators:start --only functions,firestore" or simply just "firebase emulators:start"

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are starting the Firestore emulator when you should start the Database emulator instead, as you are using the [Realtime Database onCreate() event handler](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events#set_the_event_handler).

Since you are starting the Firestore emulator, you probably don't have a Realtime Database created in the Firebase console so you get the `"Missing expected firebase config value databaseURL..."` error. You can create one following the steps of the [public documentation.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/start#create_a_database)

Or if you want to use [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore) you need to modify your code to use the [Firestore onCreate() event handler](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events#function_triggers) instead.

```
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";

const fetch = require('node-fetch');

export const newZipCode = functions.firestore.document('/zipCodes/{zipCode}').onCreate(async (snapshot, context) => {
    const api = await fetch(`https://api.papapi.se/lite/?query=${context.params.zipCode}&format=json&apikey=xxx`);
    const json = await api.json();

    console.log(context.params.zipCode);

    if (api.ok) {
        snapshot.ref.update({
            latitude: json.results[0].latitude,
            longitude: json.results[0].longitude
        });
    } else {
        console.log(${api.status}));
    }
});
```